# How to improve ESRI/ArcGIS database performance while maintaining normalization?

Tags: database, database-design

I work with databases containing spatial data.  Most of these databases are in a proprietary format created by ESRI for use with their ArcGIS software.  We store our data in a normalized data model within these geodatabases.

We have found that the performance of this database is quite slow when dealing with relationships (i.e. relating several thousand records to several thousand records can take several minutes).

Is there any way to improve performance without completely flattening/denormalizing the database or is this strictly limited by the database platform we are using?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm hearing this right -- you're asking how to improve the performance of a proprietary database, using a schema that you won't disclose. Gotcha.

Comment: The database format is not something we have created, but a format created by ESRI for use with their ArcGIS.  It is a geodatabase format designed to store GIS data.  We are limited to this as our data is created using ArcGIS and our software vendor creates software based on ArcGIS API's.  It is only the database schema we have developed that we cannot disclose.  I'm sure this is a very common situation for many businesses.

Comment: So you are asking us (your potential customers) to help you with your secret schema ? And if we happen to be ever be confronted with your product, we still have to reverse-engineer your "product" to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one way: measure. Try to obtain a query plan, and try to read it. Try to isolate a query from the logfile, edit it to an executable (non-parameterised) form, and submit it manually (in psql). Try to tune it, and see where it hurts.

Geometry joins can be costly in term of CPU, if many (big) polygons have to be joined, and if their bounding boxes have a big chance to overlap. In the extreme case, you'll have to do a preselection on other criteria (eg zipcode, if available) or maintain cache tables of matching records.

EDIT:
BTW: do you have statistics and autovacuum? IIRC, ESRI is still tied to postgres-8.3-something, where these were not run by default.

UPDATE 2014-12-11

ESRI does not interfere with non-gis stuff. It is perfectly Ok to add PK/FK relations or additional indexes to your schema. The DBMS will pick them up if appropiate. And ESRI will ignore them. (ESRI only uses its own meta-catalogs, ignoring the system catalogs)

Comment: Most queries are attribute queries, but the data has a spatial component.  We work with ESRI file geodatabases and are starting to look into ArcSDE on SQL Server 2008 R2.  Not sure yet how we will be delivering to our software vendor, which is when performance becomes an issue.

Comment: ESRI supports PostgreSQL 8.4. Personally, I'd be sorely tempted to install 9.1 and see how it works. PostgreSQL 9.1 supports "K-Nearest-Neighbor Indexing", indexing on distance.

Comment: I am not good at remembering version numbers. Dont upgrade above 8.4.something. ESRI still relies on floating-point datetime / timestamps . Which were the default some time ago. Also they fail to deliver 64bit binaries, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to deal with spatial data, I tended to precalulate the values and store them. Yes that makes for a big table but it is much faster to query when you only do the complex calculation once on data entry.  Data entry does take longer though. I was in a situation where all my spacial data came from a monthly load, so precalculating wasn't too bad.